# API Credential Error with WooCommerce

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

I have installed Paypal Express Checkout but keep getting API Credential error 3 when trying to purchase through WooCommerce. Seems to work fine through PayPal standard. Any ideas? I've re-set my API info on PayPal just in case but still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the environment is set as Live instead of sandbox.
Adding the [configuration guide](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-express-checkout/) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for that PP_MTS_hzhu, but it's already set to 'live'. Any other things I might try?